# how they are orgonized together?

Tags: magento

[image]

[image]

The above page are the right sidebar of the category page, i found they are in different `xml` file.why in the `page.xml` or `catalog.xml`,there is no code to control all of them. how are they put together?

Answer (score 1):

all layout files are processed and merged in to one big layout file then theme is built and put together based on that

Comment: if i want to delete one of them, how do i do?could you make an example?